# Why my layout view is very very different when running on device with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

This is my design on Android studio vs device (Xiaomi M2006C3MG device)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V74Gv.jpg)

Comment: could not find the differences

Answer (score 1):

please use constraint layout to avoid these types of error
or design a specific layout for every size

Answer (score 0):

it depends on theme for android version , you need to select images as per the different type of layout resolution and please make sure which theme you have used in manifest file.